# Convert Chart object to Image object C#

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I want to convert a chart object to a Image object, or if it is not possible then save the chart to a .jpg file.
I need this because I want the chart put in to a PDFSharp object..

So this is my sample code so far:

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();

            chart1.Series.Add("series1");
            chart1.Series.Add("series2");
            chart1.Series.Add("series3");

            chart1.Series["series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            chart1.Series["series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series["series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;

            Random random = new Random();

            for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
            {

                chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddY(random.Next(20, 50));
            }

            for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
            {

                chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddY(random.Next(50, 100));
            }

            for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
            {

                chart1.Series["series3"].Points.AddY(random.Next(70, 100));
            }

            chart1.SaveImage(@".\test", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Because of a reason i dont know the 'chart1.SaveImage(@".\test", ImageFormat.Jpeg);' puts out a empty file

Comment: Related tip: If your char doesn't happen to contain full-color photographs, you really should be using PNG for your chart; you'll get a smaller file without the quality loss

Comment: thank you for the hint but i get a only a white image without any chart graphics

Comment: What if you add the file extension to the filename?

Comment: @cubrr you mean (@".\test.Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) ? I also tried this

Comment: @cubr, I made step forward looks like I forget to define height and width when I have done this I will answer

Answer (score 1):

This post is about f-sharp but i think you could have the same problem. [FSharpChart.SaveAs () saves blank image if called before chart rendering is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649525/fsharpchart-saveas-saves-blank-image-if-called-before-chart-rendering-is-comp)

it looks like that the chart first have to be displayed before you can save it.